# Debian image - /sbin/init not found

Tags: docker, debian, init, molecule

I am trying to start a Debian image with the `/sbin/init` process for ansible role testing via molecule.

Yes, I am aware, that one should not start `/sbin/init` in a container unless you really have a use case for doing so. With molecule I can test my ansible roles in a docker container. As such I need `/sbin/init` running.

When I execute

```
docker run -it --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro debian:9 /sbin/init

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346:
starting container process caused "exec: \"/sbin/init\": stat /sbin/init: no such file 
or directory": unknown.
```

However, with debian:8 it works just fine.

```
docker run -it --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro debian:8 /sbin/init
```

works like a charm.

Has Debian switched to a new boot process? What changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out Debian has removed the `init` package from their docker images starting with debian:9 and newer.

That is great since it helps all of us to fail early/fast. We really should not start `/sbin/init` unless we have a use-case for doing so - and believe me, most of the time we do not.

So what to do if we really have a use-case in which we need to run `/sbin/init`?

Well, we can install it via

```
apt-get install -y init
```

If you need a Dockerfile for that

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y init && apt-get clean all
```

Comment: You need /sbin/init for any kind of Ansible testing that involves systemd (i.e. pretty much all of my playbooks).

Comment: it would help a lot if you could explain and provide resources from where we can read, why `init` inside a docker container is so dangerous.